# Get the id of current element in Admin::configureListFields

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

How to get the current object id in `Admin::configureListFields`?

`$this->getSubject()` returns `null`

Thank you

Comment: See [How to retrieve subject in Sonata configureListFields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40992129/how-to-retrieve-subject-in-sonata-configurelistfields)

Answer (score 1):

Since there are many objects in a list, your question makes no sense. I'll go ahead and assume you are in a child admin. If this is the case, I think you are looking for `$this->getParent()->getSubject()->getId()`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the way you've phrased your question I assume you ran into the same issue as I did.

My assumption is thus: You are looking to use `configureListFields` to manipulate the content of the rows of the list / the "current" element.

As greg0rie pointed out - there is a  misconception here in that there is no "current" element.

Specifically - `configureListFields` s called before the list is iterated for output so no current element exists.

Furthermore, as far as I can tell there is no method we can overwrite that is called specifically when the list is iterated over.

Therefore, what I ended up doing is the following:

First overwrite the twig template of whatever you're wanting to change in the list.

Then create a Twig extension function and pass in the "admin" and "object" properties that should be available at template level at this point:

`{{ myTwigFunction(admin, object) }}`

`admin` is the instance of the sonata admin rendering the list.

`object` is the current template.

Therefore, you now have access to the current entity object as well as the sonata admin that's handling it.

Personally I then passed this into a service to generate the changes I wanted to make.