# How to retrieve subject in Sonata configureListFields not for action?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

```
   protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {

        /** @var Article article */
        $article = $this->getSubject();
```

article is alyways null, i see [How to retrieve subject in Sonata configureListFields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40992129/how-to-retrieve-subject-in-sonata-configurelistfields)

but this solution put data to action - i need custom field (not mapped with thumb) i can do it easy if i getSubject();

I know that i can use template but creating template to get one var is strange concept

Comment: During listing you cannot get object in this function. You can access only in template.

Comment: ok, understand so need create template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should take a look at this bundle [SonataExtraAdminBundle](https://github.com/picoss/SonataExtraAdminBundle/)

It provides some extra features for Sonata such as image type in list field, or string template.

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ...
        ->add('fullname', 'string_template', array(
            'string_template' => '<span class="pull-right">{{ object.firstname }} {{ object.lastname }}</span>'
        ))
    ;
}
```